# How to make tabbar appearance non-transparent in SwiftUI, without tapping in UIKit properties?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, transparent, tabbar

```
UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

I can do this thing in swiftui controller's init method, but I want to use swiftui code to perform the same action, instead of UIKit code.

Comment: Currently, there is no way to do that directly with SwiftUI.

Comment: @Steven-Carrot It can be done in iOS 16+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75734904/1971013

Answer (score 0):

you could do a custom tabbar and customize anything you want

**First: Create the model**

```
struct TabItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var icon: String
    var tab: Tab
}

var tabItems = [
    TabItem(text: "Home", icon: "house", tab: .home),
    TabItem(text: "Serach", icon: "magnifyingglass", tab: .explore),
    TabItem(text: "Notifications", icon: "bell", tab: .notifications),
]

enum Tab: String {
    case home
    case explore
    case notifications
    case library
}
```

**Second: Apply tab bar**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab: Tab = .home
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            
            Group {
                switch selectedTab {
                case .home:
                    Text("First View")
                case .explore:
                    Text("Second View")
                case .notifications:
                    Text("Third View")
                case .library:
                    Text("Fourth View")
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            HStack {
                ForEach(tabItems) { item in
                    Button {
                        selectedTab = item.tab
                    } label: {
                        VStack(spacing: 0) {
                            Image(systemName: item.icon)
                                .symbolVariant(.fill)
                                .font(.body.bold())
                                .frame(width: 44, height: 29)
                            Text(item.text)
                                .font(.caption2)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                        }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(selectedTab == item.tab ? .primary : .secondary)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            .padding(.top, 14)
            .frame(height: 88, alignment: .top)

            .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0, style: .continuous))
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

now the tab bar style is transparent thanks to `ultraThinMaterial`

Comment: try to replace the ultraThinMaterial by on of these: regularMaterial, thickMaterial, thinMaterial, ultraThinMaterial or ultraThickMaterial. to see the difference in transparent appearance

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 16 this can be done with:

```
TabView
{
    Group
    {
        PersonsView()
        .tabItem
        {
            Label("Together", systemImage: "person.2.fill")
        }

        ...
    }
    .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
}
```

Additionally set the color with `.toolbarBackground(.gray, for: .tabBar)`.

`Group` is not needed, but it would put `.toolbarBackground()` below one of the tab items, which looks horrible.  (It must be placed inside the `TabView` block.)